# Не получается правильно составить запрос

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Добрый день. Есть таблица, которая состоит из 5 полей: `name,phone,address, date,status`.

Нужно составить запрос который вернет список дат и количество элементов разных статусов.

**К примеру**: 31 октября, было 4 записи в подтвержденным статусом, 7 с отмененным и 2 c отложенным.  Сейчас пытаюсь сделать так:

```
SELECT order_date, status FROM orders GROUP BY order_date,status ORDER BY status;
```

Но тогда возвращается просто дата и статус, а мне нужно, чтобы в каждой дате были перечислено количество всех статусов.

Comment: Количество записей получает функция `count(*)` добавьте ее в список выборки

Comment: Откуда у вас postgresql в тегах?

Comment: База postgresql.

Comment: Тогда откуда MySQL в заголовке вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order_date, sum(if(status='подтвержден',1,1)) `кол-во подтвержденных`, ... FROM orders GROUP BY order_date;
```

Comment: а можно сделать, чтобы выдавало только одну запись даты, но у нее было поля с количеством каждого статуса за данный день?

Comment: можно, обновил ответ, но будет ли это работать в постгрисе хз

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date as [Дата], status as [Статус], count(*) as [Кол-во] 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY date, status;
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Но у меня не группирует по дате, а мне нужно выводить статистику за один день по все статусам сразу. 
"2016-10-31";"confirmed";5
"2016-10-21";"confirmed";1
"2016-10-30";"confirmed";1
"2016-10-21";"canceled";2